# How to set baud rate to high speed on android

Tags: android, linux, serial-port

I am using an android device with built in serial ports, I would like to drive the port at ~3Mb/s, using stty from busybox I have set the speed to 406800b/s but cant get it up to 921600b/s; `./busybox stty -F /dev/ttyS0 921600` returns invalid argument. Typing `./busybox stty -F /dev/ttyS0`  returns

```
speed 460800 baud;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = 
^W;
lnext = <undef>; flush = <undef>; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-isig -icanon -echo
```

I think it should be possible to set it too much higher rates as the `/sys/class/tty/ttyS0/uartclk` is `104000000` so I think much higher speeds should be possible.

Are there any other ways to set the speed, I have tried microcom but that doesn't actually change the speed despite not returning an error. I have an oscilloscope attached to the serial to confirm the speed.

Comment: have you tried with -F flag, `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 921600` ?

Comment: First type `stty` in your terminal and see what settings it shows, you can see the current baud rate.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: The serial port in question of this content is too vague. In the specification of RS232C which is generally called a serial port, the maximum speed is 20Kbps. Typical interface ICs are often used up to 115.2Kbps, but more than that will depend on the hardware and device driver vendor's mindset. It seems better to confirm these specifications with the vendor.